# Applescript between 2 numbers

Tags: applescript

How do you do something like this in applescript:

if number is between 40.5 and 40.8 then
blahblahblah
end if

thanks :D

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm assuming Elijah was looking for a BETWEEN operator as I was.

Comment: Indeed SQL has an BETWEEN operator. So i expected Applescript to have one as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if 40.5 <= number and number <= 40.8 then
  do stuff...
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set num to 40.2
if 40.5 ≥ num and num ≤ 40.8 then
    display dialog "between two values"
end if
```